# How to add new elements to a list based on the previous element in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of predicted climate data. I'm trying to copy the last line of this list ten times, but replace one element with a sequential number.

My code is very simple, but it doesn't work out as I expected. The last line looks like this:

> [..., '2099', ...]`

Where `2099` is the fifth element.

**Code:**

```py
def addlist (list):
    for i in range (10):
        newline = list[-1]
        newline[4] = str(int(newline[4]) + 1)
        list.append(newline)
    return list
print(list)
```

I expect the output to be:

> [..., '2099', ...], [..., '2100', ...], ...,[..., '2109', ...]

But this code somehow deletes the `[..., '2099', ...]` line, and repeats `[..., '2109', ...]` ten times.

Why does this happen? How could I fix this?

Comment: Could you explain bit more about it? because i don't understand the question...
"I'm trying to copy the last line of this list ten times" - so your list have many lines? or you mean the last element of the list? or you have list which holds lists inside?

Comment: @emsiiggy Yes, my list has many lines, each line is a list - so it is indeed a list of list. I want to copy the last line (i.e. the last element of the entire list) and replace the fifth element of this line...does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, lists are mutable. Unless you create a new instance of the list element in your function, any operation you do will change the original list.

So in your function, the 10 lists that you added to the end were actually all the same list. Additionally, since the original list is being edited through this function, there is no need to return the final list in the end.

```
def addlist (input_list):
for i in range (10):
    newline = list(input_list[-1])
    newline[4] = str(int(newline[4]) + 1)
    input_list.append(newline)
print(list)
```

As a side note: it is best practice not to name variables after built-in names (list)